# Page write method EEPROM is overwriting after 16 bytes

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom

I am using an M24C04-R EEPROM. I am trying to do write page and read page of structure values, but it's overwriting the values after 16 bytes. uC is Renesas RX24T. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering/tuition service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show all your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 5):

From the [M24C04-R datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24c04-r.pdf):

> The Page Write mode allows up to 16 byte to be written in a single Write cycle, provided that
> they are all located in the same page in the memory: that is, the most significant memory
> address bits, A8/A4, are the same. **If more bytes are sent than will fit up to the end of the page, a “roll-over” occurs, i.e. the bytes exceeding the page end are written on the same page, from location 0.**

The M24C04-R has 16 byte pages. EEPROM chips are typically limited to writing **one page** per write command.
Due to limited internal registers and the time it needs to actually write it. (5 milliseconds for this part)

So, in order to write more than 16 bytes you have to use more page write commands.

Comment: Still I need much more because I want to write and read 63 byte size of structure.

Comment: @Dayanand that means you need 4 page writes

Comment: Yes absolutely. Can anyone send the sample code for read and write.

Comment: @Dayanand Just do what you're doing now, since you found the rollover probem, but 3 more times with data[+16] and address+16

Comment: Thank you it's working. Still any other methods.